# Looking to pull posting time from instagram using pytz and datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I am trying to pull the posting time from instagram and the datetime object gives it as ISO 8601 data string. I want to convert that to a readable date string for my local timezone.

```
import datetime
import pytz

# Getting the current UTC time
dt_utcnow = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.UTC)
print(dt_utcnow)

# Passing my ISO 8601 string to the 'fromisoformat' method
dt_utc = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat('2019-07-11T15:31:16.000')
print(dt_utc)

# Printing the current time in the NY timezone (which outputs correctly)
dt_ny_test = dt_utcnow.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
print(dt_ny_test)

# When I try to print the time using the iso string, I get unexpected output
dt_ny = dt_utc.astimezone(pytz.timezone('America/New_York'))
print(dt_ny)

# These are my results 

2019-07-11 16:14:30.489463+00:00
2019-07-11 15:31:16
2019-07-11 12:14:30.489463-04:00
2019-07-11 15:31:16-04:00

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: please format your code properly. And put the output of code below it, instead of all outputs together. Can't figure out which one is what.

Comment: btw `strftime` is what you need to format datetime. Here is a link to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior